Can I change the version of curl R is using?
Using a Windows machine with multiple versions of curl installed, can I change which version is used by the R httr package (which wraps the curl R package)?
If I check Sys.which('curl') to confirm the path and then system('curl -V') I see the expected version number.
That version number is different than what's shown with curl::curl_version()$version (a version I somehow can't find on the machine). It's an older version, and I'd like to be able to use a newer version. Or at least tell the R curl package which version I want to use. The project infrastructure is based around httr, but I'm open to other options if I can control the version of curl.
rtools, anaconda, and git, which all have a version of curl, have been recently updated, but R is still picking up the older version from somewhere. Setting the order of the Windows system variables so that rtools is on top does not make a difference with curl::curl_version()$version.

To locate "somewhere", check browseURL(system.file("libs", package="curl")) .  It´s currently built against 8.3.0. If linux builds are successfully linked against newer versions, I guess  you can at least try updating https://github.com/jeroen/curl/blob/master/tools/winlibs.R and build from source.

@margusl Found 'somewhere' - thank you!
